# How to replace Embers deprecated CollectionView

Tags: ember.js

Ember 1.13 deprecate all views as they state in their [blog](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/12/ember-1-13-0-released.html#toc_notable-deprecations-in-1-13)

I haven't found any guidance in their [deprecation guide](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view) of how to replace CollectionView. Before pushing another issue on top of the Ember issue stack on GitHub I am hoping to find an answer here for the question about how to replace CollectionView.

Comment: The same issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3440) almost 2 years ago and is marked 'close'

Answer (score 0):

You can use components and the `{{component}}` helper, and instead of managing the views directly, you manage your data.

If you want help with a specific migration try making a JSBin reproduction and ask on IRC/Slack.